# Irreducible representations in BGG category $\mathcal{O}$ over (finitely) direct sum of general linear Lie superalgebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-groups, lie-algebras, lie-superalgebras

Let $\mathfrak{g} = \oplus_i^k\mathfrak{gl}(m_i|n_i)$ be a direct sum of general linear Lie superalgebras $\mathfrak{gl}(m_i|n_i)$'s with the Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h} = \oplus_i^k \mathfrak{h}_i$, where $\mathfrak{h}_i \subset \mathfrak{gl}(m_i|n_i)$, for each $1\leq i \leq k$.

With the assumption $n_1 = n_2 =\cdots n_k =0$, it is well-known that all irreducible representations in BGG category $\mathcal{O}$ for $\mathfrak{g}$ is of the the form $L(\lambda_1) \otimes L(\lambda_2) \cdots \otimes L(\lambda_k)$, where $L(\lambda_i)$ are irreducible $\mathfrak{gl}(m_i|n_i)\cong \mathfrak{gl}(m_i)$ with highest wight $\lambda_i$, for each $1\leq i\leq k$.

We now assume the general case, that is, $n_i$'s are not necessarily zeros.

My questions

1. For given $\lambda_i \in \mathfrak{h}_i$, where $1\leq i\leq k$. Is every $L(\lambda_1) \otimes L(\lambda_2) \cdots \otimes L(\lambda_k)$ a irreducible?
2. Are every irreducible obejct in the category $\mathcal{O}$ is of the above form?

Thanks in advance!